# How to get JSON item from huge files

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to write my own program to handle information from huge JSON files.

The JSON files I am dealing with are about 3 GB when zipped and unzipping them leads to files of about 50GB. In other words, to big to be handled by simply reading them in and parsing.

A small illustration of the data is [here](https://pastebin.com/5huJGKGF) and I have the object class [here](https://pastebin.com/z2BsZwGW).

To read the data and access particular parts of the JSON file I wrote the following method

```
public static async void DeserializeJson(string inputFile)
    {
        await using FileStream file = File.OpenRead(inputFile);
        using ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(file);

        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry in zipArchive.Entries)
        {
            if (!zipArchiveEntry.Name.Contains("_Metadata"))
            {
                await using Stream entryStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open();

                IAsyncEnumerable<Total.Bbrsaglist?> enumerable = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable<Total.Bbrsaglist>(entryStream);
                
                await foreach (var item in enumerable)
                {

                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the enumerable is always empty and the foreach loop throws an exception with the message of *The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[MyNameSpace.Model.BBR.Total+Bbrsaglist]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.*

That the enumerable cannot be converted might be due to the fact that the enumerable is empty, but how can I get the items of the *Bbrsaglist* returned?

Looking further, it seems that the entryStream is also empty.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: This definitely sounds like a job for a `database`, that's build for huge data. While you can do it with json, it will be slow, because it must 'translate' your each record to find the right one.

Comment: @PoulBak I agree, however my Postgres is not willing to import the data. I believe it is due to the fact that the json file starts with { and PostgreSQL does not like that.
However, I cannot remove leading and trailing parenthesis because I cannot edit the file due to its sheer size.

Comment: Postgres would import json files that start with {. However, maximum json(b) size is 255 Mb. Your links are not working.

Comment: I don't know the content of your data but probably it is suitable for importing into a MongoDb database?

Comment: Sorry @CetinBasoz but the links do work without any problem. Thanks for the information about the max filesize for the json read to postgres.

Comment: Links were not working due to region. They work using VPN. There is plain text there JSON and C# code. Why would you put them on restricted locations instead of adding here :(

Comment: @CetinBasoz earlier experience here is that admins go bananas when posting files e.g. the c# class here.

Comment: From your link https://pastebin.com/raw/5huJGKGF it looks like your root JSON container is an object, not an array: `{ "BBRSagList": [ /* Array Contents */ ] }`.  The method [`JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsyncEnumerable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserializeasyncenumerable) *Wraps the UTF-8 encoded text into an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` that can be used to deserialize **root-level JSON arrays** in a streaming manner.*  Since your JSON is not a root level array, you can't use this method.

Comment: Also, the JSON at the external link is malformed.  Upload it to https://jsonlint.com/ and you will get an error *Error: Parse error on line 38: `}, , {` Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got ','*.  So maybe your "real" root container really is an array?

Comment: Please do try to provide a [mcve] with code + well-formed JSON in the question itself.  From [ask]: *Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.*

Answer (score 0):

As dbc mentions in the comments, the reason is most likely that your json is not a "root-level JSON arrays".

That gives you a few options

1. Hack the file to make it into an "root-level JSON array". From your example it looks like you could simply remove the top level list object.
2. Write your own parser. If you just have lots of data but little variation it might be feasible to just write your own simplified json parser that can process the file object by object.
3. Throw hardware at the problem. Unless you run into some framework limitation there is nothing inherently problematic with 50Gb of data, just make sure you have say 128Gb of ram. In some cases it can be cheaper to throw hardware at the problem rather than development time.

I would also take a hard look at your storage strategy that got you into this mess in the first place. A database, sql or no sql, *might* be appropriate. But if you mainly want to store data and not query it, I would look to some binary serialization format instead of json. That should give you an uncompressed size much closer to your 3Gb compressed size, and I would expect it to perform better. I have used Protobuf .net, but there are several other libraries, just avoid BinaryFormatter. You might also consider splitting your data in more easily manageable chunks, you could for example try saving each object as an individual zip-entry.

Comment: I got the part with the "not a 'root-level JSON array[s]'" but you are loosing me with the options you suggest.

  1. in my first comment I state that the file is so big that I can only view but not edit it.
  2. As you can see from the code in the post, I am in the process of writing my parser, and have problems to access the JSON data the right way.
  3. is not an option.

The part with my "storage strategy" escapes entirely. I am the one who has to handle the JSON file, and yes, it should of course go into a database. I have no idea why somebody would exchange such data in JSON anyway

Comment: @TomGeo With option 1 I mean something like reading the stream until you find the array, i.e. the first `[` character, backing the stream and letting `DeserializeAsyncEnumerable` do the rest. Regarding option 2, your example is *not* of a parser, it just a wrapper around the `JsonSerializer`. See [Let's build a compiler](https://compilers.iecc.com/crenshaw/) for an introduction to parsing. If you are not responsible for generating the data, you need to talk to someone who is, and agree on a better format.